# SoundBlaster SB-Z: No Control Panel

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

Updated the Soundblaster drivers to the [latest](https://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&subCatID=1005&prodID=21402&prodName=Sound%20Blaster%20Z&subCatName=Z-Series&CatName=) on 1909:18363.1256. The driver install process completed without error and noted there was no difference in the ensuing install dialogs as to whether it was Full, Compact, or Custom. Most likely defaulted to Compact. Rebooted.

Sound works, but the SBZ.exe (at least that is what it used to be) CP gui executable is not created. The Sound Blaster Audio Service is running.
Related thread is at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SoundBlasterOfficial/comments/hnr10s/soundblaster_z_control_panel_dont_work_again_in/), from where the idea of this command was attempted

```
regsvr32 nlsdl.dll
```

> The module "nlsdl.dll" was loaded but the entry-point
> DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that "nlsdl.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try
> again.

The actual issue seems to be more fundamental than just nlsdl.dll. Do possess an old cd archive of the gui program with the following version dated ~2012:

```
[Version]
SoftwareSubPath = Sound Blaster Z-Series Control Panel
SoftwareID = SOUND_BLASTER_Z-SERIES_CONTROL PANEL
SoftwareVersion = 2.15.04
SoftwareFriendlyName = Sound Blaster Z-Series Control Panel
```

Can that be resurrected somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Actually had to install the [software](https://support.creative.com/downloads/download.aspx?nDownloadId=100279) item on the d/l page for the control panel.

However, serendipity strikes again! Creative have just posted [Command](https://support.creative.com/downloads/download.aspx?nDownloadId=100343) for a whole range of cards, so driver and software all in the same bundle as it was back in 2011.